# Why do downloads from firebasestorage URL fail when called from IIS context?

Tags: c#, iis

I am getting a strange behavior when trying to download files from my web service.

My web service is a .net service based in IIS. One task it has is to retrieve images from URLs that are given as a part of its workflow. This generally works. We have a new requirement to support downloads from firebasestorage URLs. This seems pretty straightforward, but for some reason, it doesn't work when the IIS-based web service tries to download.

If I use the same code in a standalone application, the download works fine. The error is a response from the googleapis, so there must be some difference in the way the call is made, but I don't see what it is.

The basic code looks like this (client specific information is scrubbed):

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    Uri uri = new Uri("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/hidden.appspot.com/o/images%2F20182248141Image.jpg?alt=media&token=******-474d-4693-a36c-dfee***cb9c4"); 
    wc.DownloadFileAsync(uri, @"c:\temp\Image.jpg");
}
```

If I run the above snippet in C# interactive window or in a standalone app, the file will download.

If I run the snippet with the context of IIS, then the WebClient reports: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Comment: I ended up routing these specific files to a different library that works in the IIS context. I'd still be interested to hear any thoughts about why WebClient won't download from firebasestorage from within IIS.